# javascript is not working with intel XDK on linux ( Ubuntu 14 )

Tags: intel-xdk, intel-xdk-contacts

Is there any problem in using javascript in intel xdk on ubuntu. simple alert message wont work in ubuntu which the same works with windows installation.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blank App Designer Cordova Web App Project Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>           
    <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>     
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('hi')">click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say not working on Ubuntu, are you talking about running it in the emulator?

Comment: yes , in emulator the alert is not coming, same code in windows its working

Comment: What happens if you call alert from the debug console?  Are there any errors there?